# SQL Server queries case sensitivity

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-ce, case-sensitive

I have this database:

```
abcDEF

ABCdef

abcdef
```

if I write: `select * from MyTbl where A='ABCdef'`

how to get:  `ABCdef`

and how to get:

```
abcDEF

    ABCdef

    abcdef
```

Thanks in advance

forgot to write - sqlCE

Comment: Uppercase/Lowecase, not big/small.

Answer (score 34):

You can make your query case sensitive by making use of the [`COLLATE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa174903(SQL.80).aspx) keyword.

```
SELECT A 
FROM MyTbl 
WHERE A COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS = 'ABCdef'
```

Answer (score 6):

If you have abcDEF, ABCdef, abcdef already in the database then it's already case sensitive or you have no constraint.

You'd have to add a `COLLATE` on both sides to make sure it's truly case sensitive (for a non case sensitive database) which will invalidate index usage

```
SELECT TheColumn
FROM MyTable 
WHERE TheColumn COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS = 'ABCdef' COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS
```

What about accents too? `Latin1_General_CS_AI`, `Latin1_General_Bin`?

Answer (score 3):

Try this just add binary keyword after `where`:

```
select * from MyTbl where binary A = 'ABCdef';
```

Answer (score 1):

It's all about collation. Each one has a suffix (CI and CS, meaning Case Insensitive, and Case Sensitive).

http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/10894_3302341_2/SQL-Server-and-Collation.htm

Answer (score 1):

SQL is non-case-sensitive by default, so you will get all three items if doing a simple string comparison.  To make it case-sensitive, you can cast the value of the field and your search value as varbinary:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTbl WHERE CAST(A AS varbinary(20)) = CAST('ABCdef' as varbinary(20))
```

The above assumes your varchar field is sized at 20. For nvarchar double it (thanks @ps2goat).

Comment: -1 Whow. That is the worst answer possible - take out all indices, force a table scan and totally ignore the reality of being able to change the collation ;)

Comment: @TomTom - Using `COLLATE` means the indices won't be used anyway.

Comment: I'm sure there are worse answers -- that query at least functions.  From my understanding there's no way to specify case insensitivity using indexes unless you're doing a binary comparison.  I've never tried it, but if your table column was defined as a VARBINARY, you could do an index on that and only have to cast your search string.

Comment: wouldn't an nvarchar be 40 bytes if it was 20 characters long?