# Case Sensitive String Comparison

Tags: sql-server, string, t-sql, stored-procedures

I need to compare two strings in a If-Else block in a stored procedure such as

```
If(@USERNAME='rajat')
begin
select * from table
end
else
begin
select * from table1
end
```

but the problem with the above approach is '=' comparison is case insensitive.I need a approach where the comparison is case sensitive

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Case Sensitive String Compare](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3969059/sql-case-sensitive-string-compare)

Comment: Possible duplicate.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387378/sql-server-queries-case-sensitivity?rq=1

Comment: case sensitivity has nothing to do with the equals sign.
Case sensitivity is determined by the collation for the database

Answer (score 11, accepted):

SQL Server has case sensitivity at the server, database, and column level. This is part of the [collation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143726.aspx) properties. So in your example, it's likely that one or more of these settings has been set to case-insensitive.

```
-- Check server collation
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('COLLATION')

-- Check database collation.
SELECT DATABASEPROPERTYEX('AdventureWorks', 'Collation') SQLCollation;

-- Check column collation
select table_name, column_name, collation_name
from information_schema.columns
where table_name = @table_name
```

Something like this SQL might work for you:

```
If (@USERNAME='rajat' COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS)
.....
```

Comment: +1 For actually providing an explanation with your answer, and other relevant information, rather than just posting working code with no other information. This appears to be a dying art on Stackoverflow.

Comment: Is it more efficient to use a collate casting instead of using upper() or lower function? and collate could depending of the collation used the problem to change some character

Comment: @MatheseF, upper/lower functions deal only with case sensitivity. Collate also deals with sorting rules and accent sensitivity. I don't know which is more performant.

Comment: @MatheseF, also see answers to this SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6145687/affecting-performance-with-sql-collation.

Answer (score 4):

Another way to force case sensitivity is to `convert`/`cast` both arguments to `varbinary` types:-

```
declare @string1 as varchar(50) = 'abc'
declare @string2 as varchar(50) = 'ABC'

if @string1 = @string2
    print 'same'
else
    print 'different'

if convert(varbinary(50),@string1) = convert(varbinary(50),@string2)
    print 'same'
else
    print 'different'
```

produces:-

```
same
different
```

Answer (score 3):

```
If(@USERNAME='rajat' COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS )
begin
select * from table
end
else
begin
select * from table1
end
```