# PHP MySQL: Search query work only with existing full term

Tags: php, mysql, sql, search

I got a search query fully work but only if i use the correct term (i.e. 'iPhone 6 Plus' but if i search only 'iPhone' it will return nothing.

My search query is: `SELECT * FROM products WHERE name LIKE '" . $term . "' OR brand LIKE '" . $term . "' LIMIT 0 , 30"`

So how I can create a better query that can search better?

Thanks a Lot to all who can help.

Comment: RTM http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/pattern-matching.html the solution is rather quite simple.

Comment: so I must to use %$term%?

Comment: *You got it Pontiac* ;-)

Comment: vedere Jay's rispota ;-)

Comment: prego Andrea. Can you elaborate on that? You mean that if someone enters `iphone` as opposed to `iPhone` it will fail? edit: ah, you deleted your comment. edit #2: ah, there you are lol

Comment: yes, i've deleted cause i've wrote the question on Jay's answer

Comment: yes, it fail, so if I use 'iphone' got a null reply, but if I use 'iPhone' return the result

Comment: see if this Q&A helps http://stackoverflow.com/q/1831105/ and http://stackoverflow.com/q/3387378/ in conjunction with Jay's answer and his comment.

Answer (score 2):

In order to do matches on partial search terms you have to add some [wildcards](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html) to your queries, the `%`:

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE name COLLATE UTF8_GENERAL_CI LIKE '%" . $term . "%' OR brand COLLATE UTF8_GENERAL_CI LIKE '%" . $term . "%' LIMIT 0 , 30"
```

You could just add `COLLATE UTF8_GENERAL_CI` to your column definitions and then you would not have to modify your queries. For example:

```
ALTER TABLE products MODIFY COLUMN name VARCHAR(...) CHARACTER SET UTF8 COLLATE UTF8_GENERAL_CI.
```

If you need something more complex you will want to look a [fulltext searches](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html).

The Latin collation (`LATIN1_GENERAL_CS`)is one of those which is known to work well with case insensitive searches. If the one I specified (I try to always use UTF-8) doesn't work, substitute the Latin collation.

Comment: Thanks Jay! but is case sensitive, there is a way to search without case sensitives?

Comment: Ah - you didn't indicate that earlier. Outside of something much more complex [it is all about the collation used](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case-sensitivity.html) on the table @andreaem See my update.

Comment: Don't work, got no result even if i use 'iPhone' instead of 'iphone'

Comment: Did you alter the table? Or the query?

Comment: Nope, if i send the query using PHPmyadmin i got this: COLLATION 'UTF8_GENERAL_CI' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'binary'

Comment: If that is the case you might have to modify your MySQL .ini file and restart. Try my suggested change above first though.

Comment: Thanks, i've Alter the table but nothing changed, what type of modify to do in my.cfg ?

Comment: Can you run `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%char%';` first and post the results?

Comment: I got character_set_client
utf8
character_set_connection
utf8
character_set_database
utf8
character_set_filesystem
binary
character_set_results
utf8
character_set_server
latin1
character_set_system
utf8
character_sets_dir
/usr/share/mysql/charsets/

Comment: Make sure `character-set-server = utf8` and `collation-server = utf8_general_ci` are uncommented in your my.cnf. If you make a change to the file you'll have to restart your MySQL server.

Comment: I haven't these lines in my.cfg so I've added and restart mysql, retry the search and got nothing

Comment: character_set_client
utf8
character_set_connection
utf8
character_set_database
utf8
character_set_filesystem
binary
character_set_results
utf8
character_set_server
utf8
character_set_system
utf8
character_sets_dir
/usr/share/mysql/charsets/

Comment: The character set changed properly. Can you setup a SQL fiddle?

Comment: Damn, i'm not able, how can I do?

Comment: Case insensitivity works there right out of the gate @andreaem :-/ http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0069ab/2 Your column collation is ` COLLATE utf8_bin`

Comment: Yes, i see and working using query posted on your answer, i can't understand why not working on my c9 workspace

Comment: Try with  `COLLATE utf8_bin` in the query.

Comment: i've tried to change the query as `SELECT * FROM 'products' WHERE name LIKE '%" . $term . "%' OR brand LIKE '%" . $term . "%SELECT * FROM products WHERE name COLLATE utf8_bin LIKE '%" . $term . "%' OR brand COLLATE utf8_bin LIKE '%" . $term . "%' LIMIT 0 , 30`

Comment: At this point, without being able to look at your MySQL server configuration, it would be hard to know what to try next. Everything that we have done to this point should have gotten you up and running. You could try recreating the table using a non-binary collation (still use UTF-8 though) and see if that works. If not, try one of the Latin collations.

Comment: I've tried to delete and import again, nothing changed... Thanks Jay, don't worry, let it be for now and I will back to this later